# How to include folders projects for sonar analysis which are not part of solution using sonar scanner for .net

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

How do I configure the sonar to include folders or projects which are not part of the current .net solution. I have the following structure my current project:

MyProject - Root Folder
ProjectA - Normal .net project
ProjectB
**MyProject.Services**
MyProject.Services - This is a asp.net core project
MyProject.Services.sln
MyProject.Services.Model
MyProject.Services.Repository
MyProject.sln

[folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmhL1.png)

MyProject.Services is a separate solution having .net core project. During the sonar analysis - it is only analyzing the files associated with MyProject.sln. The requirement is to include files from MyProject.Services as well to have a single report for both solutions.

I tried to include it as a parameter (sonar.sources) but got below error:
File "..." can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

We are using a powershell script for the sonar begin/end step which is getting executed through bamboo build job.

Sonar Scanner:
C:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.6.0.1930-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe
Sonarqube version: 8.9

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar C# and Sonar VB.NET analyzers are Roslyn analyzers, so you need to build a project/solution to get the analysis results. So, if you want issues for `MyProject.Services` you will have to build it.

You can include the results for multiple MSBuild projects/solutions in the same Sonar project - just build the required projects between the Scanner `begin` and `end` steps e.g.

- run the scanner `begin` step
- build `MyProject.Services.sln`
- build `MyProject.sln`
- run the scanner `end` step